# AWS SES template #lt conditional statement not working

Tags: amazon-ses

I'm using AWS SES templates with conditional statements documented in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/message-template-helpers.html ?

For some reason I can't get the following simple statement to work:

```
{{#lt balance '0'}}
  <p>blah blah...</p>
{{/lt}}
```

The balance I pass in is a Java long value. The error message I'm getting from AWS SES is:

An error occurred (MissingRenderingAttribute) when calling the TestRenderTemplate operation: Attribute 'lt' is not present in the rendering data.

It seems to think #lt is a rendering attribute, when in fact it's a handlebars conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you provided is for Pinpoint.  SES only supports the basic handlebars helpers.  You have to implement a custom handlebars helper function, which I think you have to do before sending it to the SendTemplatedEmailCommand.